# Multiple div with same class. How to apply JS hover effect on a particular div among them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-4

I am having same div name for multiple div (which comes in a foreach loop). Now I want to have an effect of js hover on the particular div which is touched by that time by mouse pointer .

I mean if I hover on 3rd div with the same name of other 10 div ... it apply the hover effect to the 3rd div only.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".hover").hover(function (e) {
        $("#hovsw").show();
    }, function (e) {
        $("#hovsw").hide();
    });
});
```

now my div is like that

```
@foreach($questions_all as $question_each)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default hover">
            panel to be touched
            <div id="hovsw">
                effect of js ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

As the for-each generate multiple div it takes the first one and changed it according to the js.

Comment: Generating duplicate ids in HTML document is bad practice try classes instead

Comment: _I mean if I hover on 3rd div with the same name of other 10 div_ that is not good.

Comment: [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: This is on foreach loop... how can I manage it . Please assist ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look inside the element you're hovering for what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".hover").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).find('.hovsw').show();
    }, function (e) {
        $(this).find('.hovsw').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cant do that . Want each div work with this js effect in every individual interactions with them.

Comment: I was misunderstanding you. Updating my answer.

Comment: I've updated it. Change your html from `id="hovsw"` to `class="hovsw"` since duplicate `id` attributes are not allowed.